# Whats the correct WHM setup for AWS EC2 with ROUTE53 custom nameservers

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameserver

1. I currently have a reseller hosting account, and I want to setup and move everything to a new hosting platform on AWS
2. I have setup an EC2 instance on AWS and installed WHM. Its running fine.
3. I setup white label nameservers at my domain registrar and AWS ROUTE53 (ns1.myname.com)

(I'm just using ns1 as an example, but have repeated the same for ns2,ns3 and ns4)

- At my domain registrar = I pointed ns1.myname.com to the AWS ROUTE53 assigned ns1 IP add (87.65.43.21)
- At AWS ROUTE53 I created an A record for ns1.myname.com to point to the AWS EC2 public IP for the WHM server (12.34.56.78)
- I then setup the first new account (acc1.com) in WHM. The IP is the same as the AWS EC2 public IP for the WHM server (12.34.56.78)

PROBLEM

1. acc1.com wont load. browser returns = This site can’t be reached acc1.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
2. Using MXTOOLBOX.COM when checking acc1.com the DNS it returns = Loop detected! We were referred back to '12.34.56.78'
3. Using MXTOOLBOX.COM when checking myname.com the DNS is okay, no loop detected. It justs point to '12.34.56.78'
4. Using MXTOOLBOX.COM when checking ns1.myname.com the DNS is okay, no loop detected. It justs point to '12.34.56.78'

QUESTION

1. Where did I go wrong! I suspect the problem is at WHM, do I need to fix a config that allows the WHM to route the traffic to the newly created accounts?
2. I started reading about dns cluster. But I only have 1 WHM server, so I dont need too or don't have another to cluster with.

Comment: This would fit much better on serverfault. And the people who can help you are over there too 

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember to go there next time. Anyway I've finally figured it out for anyone else that has the same problem.
Its just that I needed to open up the BIND ports for public DNS server access. Add Incoming TCP/UDP ports 53 in the EC2 instance Security Group (AWS firewall)

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @Dr.Ping note that unless things have changed, at least some questions involving WHM and similar "control panels" are [off-topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/8095/153161) at Server Fault, since they are not commonly used by professional systems administrators, and installing them on a system tends to make expertise-based troubleshooting more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out for anyone else that has the same problem. Its just that I needed to open up the BIND ports for public DNS server access. Add Incoming TCP/UDP ports 53 in the EC2 instance Security Group (AWS firewall)

Answer (score 0):

To create Child NameServer on AWS.
Create two A record for ns1 and ns2.
Then create Two NameServer and use value as A record.
Like

```
A > ns1 > 1.2.3.4
A > ns2 > 1.2.3.4
NS > ns1 > ns1.example.com
NS > ns2 > ns2.example.com
```